# How would I compare a list (or equivalent) to another list in c++

Tags: c++

I am attempting to learn C++ from scratch and possess a medium amount of python knowledge.
Here is some of my python code which takes a number, turns it into a list and checks if it contains all digits 0-9. If so it returns True, if not it returns False.

```
def val_checker(n):
values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
lst = []
for i in range(len(str(n))):
    lst.append((n // 10 ** i) % 10)
lst = lst[::-1]
return all(i in lst for i in values)
```

How would I achieve a similar thing in C++?

Comment: you are asking about one tiny detail when you should rather start from the start. The c++ code will look very different, knowing python helps a little but not that much. Do you know how to create a list of digits from an integer in C++? Before you got that, there is nothing to be compared

Comment: You convert an integer to string just to get its length, then drop it and doing cumbersome arithmetic with it. Once, it's a string it should be very easy to extract all digits (regardless whether in Python or C++).

Comment: Your title doesn't say what your question says. It's a very generic question you have asked. If you want to do a task like this, first break it down to individual components. How to make a list, what sort of container suits your application (a list would be a std::vector), how to loop through a list, what the basic operators of modulo, quotient, etc. are. Comparing two integer lists simply can be done with `if (a==b)` similar to python `if a ==b`.

Comment: No container necessary - just arithmetic: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/397c05855ac994b5). (OK. `mask` could be seen as a "bit container" but it's just an `int`.)

Answer (score 0):

You would use the standard library container `std::set` or better yet `std::unordered_set`
This container will hold at most one of each distinct element, duplicates insertions are ignored.

So you can run through your original number in a loop, adding each digit into the set, and consider success if `s.size() == 10` if your set is called s